# XMonad: how to bind Super (Win key) + Space to keyboard layout switch?

Tags: haskell, emacs, key-bindings, xmonad, keyboard-layout

I used to switch keyboard layout pressing <kbd>❖ win</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> on Windows 8, and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> on OS X.

However, on Linux I have <kbd>❖ win</kbd> key dedicated to XMonad as modificator key. So, to switch between layouts I have to use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>.

This was not a problem until I've installed Emacs. Now I'm able to use all <kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> key combinations, because I have <kbd>alt</kbd> as <kbd>meta</kbd> *(<kbd>⎋ escape</kbd> could help, but it's very unhandy)*.

I think the easiest workaround for this case is to configure <kbd>❖ win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to layout switch combination. Though XMonad by default use this combination to switching layouts, I rarely cycle layouts in both direction, so I will happy to have <kbd>❖ win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for switching keyboard layout, and <kbd>❖ win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to switch XMonad layout. If I could make such configuration I will be able to use <kbd>alt</kbd> key as <kbd>meta</kbd> in Emacs.

However, I don't know how to make XMonad to use <kbd>❖ win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> as keyboard switch combination, being more preciese I don't know is it even possible.

Comment: Just a short remark: ``-- bla`` is for single line comments, ``{- bla -}`` for multiline comments.

Comment: (: surely, I rarely use multiline comments personally, and here is I've tried to force SO frontend to render comment as comment (I've expected light gray colour), but it is very stubborn. `-- blah` is rendered in black color, this brings ambiguity, do you see it (`++ ++ -- ++`)? fixed now (;

Comment: @deshtop, by the way thank you and `mhwombat`

Comment: You should cut and paste your solution from the question into an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @dfeuer, I've never seen that I could edit an answer! Good idea. By the way, there is one caveat in this solution: both `rWin` and `Win+Space` key sequences triggers layout change. If you _(accidently)_ pressed `rWin`, the layout changes; then if you press `Win+Space` and layout changes again, but XMonad's bindings (I use Win key as XMonad modifier) does not work, you have to press `rWin` again to be able use XMonad keys. I'm still trying to figure out what is the best method to change layout. Maybe Xkb plugin should be the solution.

Comment: Also I'm trying to find almost identical configuration for my keys on macbook and linux machine, so I suppose to change XMonad mod—key to left Ctrl. Idealy I want to know the way to trigger keyboard layout (input method) change only by specified key combination (e.g. Win+Space). It seems there is no such option avail for XkbOption, in this case I prefer not to have any keybinding at Xkb side at all (e.g. configure key binding in XMonad config only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've got to do is unbind `Win-Space` (using `removeKeys`), and create bindings for xmonad-layout switching and keyboard-layout switching (using `additionalKeys` or `additionalKeysP`). 
[Details and examples in the documentation](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-EZConfig.html).
The keyboard-layout switching command can be launched by using `spawn` from the Core library.

Comment: @destop, I'm aware of functions you mentioned above, and I've actually come to solution you offering, though was not able to implement it. The piece I've  missing is command to spawn, i.e. I don't know exact command to switch layout in Linux. I've tried to spawn `setkbdmap`, but this is not what I need. Can you point me such command?

Comment: I think the command you need is `setxkbmap`. Check the man pages and experiment at the command line to verify the exact command you want, and then add the spawn command to your xmonad.hs.

Comment: I've added my solution to question body, though it's work as expected I've  found that having single right `Win` as layout switcher is quite good alternative to any `Win`+`Space` combination. Cheers!

Comment: The link in this answer is broken. Anybody knows where it should point to?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this with a shell (zsh) script saved on my path as *cycle-keyboard-layout*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

total_layouts="${#@}"
current_layout=$(setxkbmap -query | awk '/layout:/{ print $2 }')
current_index="${@[(i)$current_layout]}"
next_index="$((current_index % total_layouts + 1))"
next_layout="${@[$next_index]}"

setxkbmap "$next_layout"
```

Then, in my *xmonad.hs* I include:

```
import XMonad.Util.CustomKeys (customKeys)

altMask = mod1Mask

main =
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
    { keys = customKeys delkeys inskeys
    , modMask = mod4Mask
    }

inskeys :: XConfig l -> [((KeyMask, KeySym), X ())]
inskeys conf@XConfig {modMask = modMask} =
  [ -- modMask + alt + space
  , ((modMask .|. altMask, xK_space),
        spawn "cycle-keyboard-layout dvorak us")
  ]

delkeys :: XConfig l -> [(KeyMask, KeySym)]
delkeys XConfig {} = []
```

And now <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> (I use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> for other things) switches my layout between dvorak and us qwerty. To use other layouts, just replace `dvorak us` with a space separated list of layouts which can be set with `setxkbmap layout`.

My full bare bones *xmonad.hs* is at https://github.com/schlueter/xmonad-config/blob/master/xmonad.hs.